# How can I dynamically change record textbox hieghts in my report to the same as the highest for each record?

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, height

I have a report with two fields (txtQuestion & txtLookingFor) which is populated via a query. Sometimes txtQuestion is much longer than txtLookingFor (or vice versa) and I want the printed report to appear even, by making the shorter of the two equal in height to the longer of the two - for each record on this report.

I have some VBA which is triggered by even "Detail OnFormat" which is supposed to retrive the "height" values of each of the text boxes, find the maximum, and set both heights to this value. I cannot seem to get (read) the height values (from each record). But I can manually set the height values (per record) to some arbitrary value via VBA if I want.

I have tried all the "Can Grow" and "Can Shrink" options. My text boxes do grow to their own height (per record), but I cannot seem to read what that value is, for use in my VBA code.

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    maxheight = 100
    If (Me.txtQuestion.Height > maxheight) Then 
         maxheight = Me.txtQuestion.Height
    End If
    If (Me.txtLookingFor.Height > maxheight) Then 
         maxheight = Me.txtLookingFor.Height
    End If
    Me.txtQuestion.Height = maxheight
    Me.txtLookingFor.Height = maxheight
    Me.txtNotes.Height = maxheight
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try `On Current` event?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I found on tek-tips that gives a general idea of how to make textboxes look the same height by drawing rectangles around them. The controls themselves are not resizable.

```
Private Sub Detail_Print(Cancel As Integer, PrintCount As Integer)
    Dim intMaxHeight As Integer
    Dim ctl As Control
    'Find highest control in Detail section that has a tag property of "Border"
    For Each ctl In Me.Section(0).Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "Border" Then
            If ctl.Height > intMaxHeight Then
                intMaxHeight = ctl.Height
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'Draw a box around each control in Detail that has a tag property of "Border"
    For Each ctl In Me.Section(0).Controls
        If ctl.Tag = "Border" Then
            Me.Line (ctl.Left, ctl.Top) - Step(ctl.Width, intMaxHeight), vbBlack, B
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Reference:
https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1676341

Answer (score 0):

Just paste the growing / shrinking textbox in left and right side and link both text box controls with the same field. Change the text colour property of left side text box to white. Then position another text box above the same left side text box and change its property to 'Bring to Front'. Everything is OK and working Properly. Even the lines drawn in between will move accordingly.

Comment: actually i searched in this website for the answer, then came such an idea. i just shared that. may be useful to somebody